# Does FIlezilla (or FTP in general) have any sniffer protection?

Tags: security, ftp, filezilla, sniffing

Is possible track credentials of a normal Filezilla connection (no SFTP) in the same wifi with methods like "Man in the Middle", or the program have any security about this?

Comment: See [What are the risks of using FTP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/145008/43677) or [Is it possible to get all the data I send through wifi?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6946/43677).

Answer (score 1):

Client programs alone cannot provide any "sniffer protection" unless the server also supports it – in other words, the *protocol* must have that capability. (The server must know how to unprotect the data!)

So in the case of "plain FTP", the answer is no. That's one of the reasons it's called "plain FTP".

The primary "sniffer protection" mechanism in FTP is provided by **FTPS**, which is essentially the same TLS (SSL) as in HTTPS. Since it is *not* a brand new protocol (unlike SFTP), there's a chance of your server already supporting it. Enable FTPS in FileZilla and see if it works.

(Sometimes FTPS is not active by default because of various NAT-related problems, as firewalls and NAT routers actually rely on being able to see the FTP control traffic! It's possible to configure a server such that it works perfectly with FTPS in "passive" mode even behind a firewall, but not all FTP server operators do that.)

There are other mechanisms besides TLS to protect either all traffic or just the login credentials (again this needs client *and* server support) – but I'm not aware of any FTP software implementing that. (For example, the FTP protocol integrates the SASL framework which could offer several means of secure authentication and even transport encryption, but no client or server can use it as far as I remember.)